# How to test command anacron?

Tags: linux, cron, filesystems

```
uname -r
4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

I have appended `0 0 test touch ~/ana.cron` to `/etc/anacrontab`. But there is no effect after rebooting or resuming from sleep or running `sudo anacron -f`. I can't find the output file `ana.cron`.

`cat /etc/anacrontab`

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1   5   cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7   25  cron.weekly     nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45 cron.monthly        nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
0 0 test touch ~/ana.cron
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *period* can be of 0.

```
1 0 test.daily nice run-parts touch ~/ana.cron
```

If you want your task to be run at startup, then use `@reboot`

```
@reboot test.reboot nice run-parts touch ~/ana.cron
```

Comment: I have tried your code `@reboot test.reboot touch ~/ana.cron`. It does not work.

Comment: @BigShield, then this `nice run-parts` thing must be necessary? See my edit.